# Change background color of Cell on swipe to delete

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

Is it possible to change background color of cell  when user swipes it to get the delete button. I have searched a lot for it but did not get any solution.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Post your code what you tried uptil now are you implementing the SwipeGesture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will help you:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

According to official documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3awillBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath%3a), this `UITableViewDelegate` method is tailor made for such kind of work.

> In this "swipe to delete" mode the table view does not display any
>   insertion, deletion, and reordering controls. This method gives the
>   delegate an opportunity to adjust the application's user interface
>   to editing mode.

**EDIT**:: According to the comment you want to capture the event when user does not delete the cell but swipe to end the editing mode. For this, we have the following delegate:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
      cell.backgroundColor = originalColor;
}
```

Comment: Thanks punit your answer does help . It changes background colour but than how to get back to original bg colour (i.e bg colour before swiping) of that cell again when user swipes to remove delete button without deleting it. Hope you are getting me :)

Comment: I would encourage you to read the documentation for which I provided the link to. That document contains all the UITableViewDelegate methods. Anyways, see my edit. It shows how to capture event when user moves away from editing mode.